# Remote data annotation issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Technology: ASP.NET MVC

I have used Remote data annotation for checking unique user name for "Register" action which is a member of "Account" controller. This is working fine. But the problem is in "Account" controller I also have "Login" action method and when I try to login it says "UserName is already exists."
This remote error message should work only with "Register" action

Can someone help me to resolve this issue.

[Remote("isUserNameAvailable","Account",AdditionalFields ="Register", ErrorMessage ="User Name is already exists")]

public string UserName { get; set; }

Thanks

Moved this action in different controller but still it has same issue.

Answer (score 0):

OK guys after struggling I got the solution on this which is very simple.

Create a new Login Class and there add UserName property without remote annotation and use this class / model into your view.

That's it!!!